# Is redeclaring an optional parameter using optional binding supported?

Tags: ios, swift

If a function call receives an optional parameter, adding an optional binding re-declaring the parameter seems to work as expected. Any code under the optional binding uses the new non-optional type.

```
    func foo(notification: NSNotification?) {

    guard let notification = notification else {
        return
    }

    ... // do something with the non optional notification object
```

But every example I see checks if the parameter is nil first, if not nil, they simply use that same parameter variable. In my particular example, I'm basically redeclaring the notification variable to a non optional type. This is something that cannot be done in objective c, it gives a compiler error. Since I'm not knowledgeable on the internal implementation of optional bindings, was curious to know if this is the way to approach this problem, or I need to use a different variable name.

Comment: Did you try it? What's the question? (I'm not being petty - I really don't see what the problem is.) Unless you're texting while driving, you've got a computer in front of you: try it. No need to waste SO bandwidth on this sort of thing.

Comment: It's not only correct but the recommended way of doing it. Have a look at the [Ray Wenderlich Swift Style Guide](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide#optionals)

Comment: Sorry to waste your time @matt. I tried it and it works, my question was more about the recommended way.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you'd even accept an optional variable if you just immediately return when it's `nil`.  Seems like the appropriate thing to do would be to not accept optional values.

Comment: As far as "the recommended way", that's going to be primarily opinion based.

Comment: The reason being in the case of an objc SDK that has a delegate callback with an object parameter which I don't really know if it is optional or not. We use a framework that was making our app crash because the value sometimes was nil, where we were expecting a non-optional value. If they decide to send a nil value, we don't crash anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is generally a recommended pattern in swift.

There's generally no need to cast a passed optional to an internal variable unless you're wanting to mutate it internally, and it looks like you're using guard properly, when you're wanting to exit a function before any other code runs if the parameter is nil.

Comment: My issue was since the new variable will use the same parameter name. The new instance will not be an optional, hence my question. So I'm not modifying it, but I do need to know it was unwrapped correctly.

Comment: After the guard statement, notification will be seen as an NSNotification (non-optional), not an NSNotification?.  if notification is nil, the else block from the guard will be executed.

Comment: Thanks. I just needed confirmation that this was the case, and that this is a normal pattern.